# Computer keep restarting continuously no display

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard, desktop-computer

I just set up the new computer, the PC is turned on but it keeps restarting after a second with No display

**Here is the config:**

Motherboard: BIOSTAR TB360-BTC PRO

https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=1031#memorysupport

Cpu:

https://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/SR/SR3X9.html

Ram: kvr26n19s8/4

http://findhard.ru/en/rams/model?id=9398&m=kingston-kvr26n19s64

Power: Great Wall GW-EPS1650DA 1650W Gold Full Module

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002939155040.html

No hard drive, no graphic card.

**What I did with no luck:**

- I tried to remove the ram stick insert again in the different ram channel, and restart the MB battery, ...
- Tried one different ram stick but not work
- Tried boot pc without ram, but now it not restarting but still no display
- Tried re-insert CPU but no lock
- I also read a lot of forum posts and try solutions but it seems my case is different

**Update:**

I just tried to connect the motherboard speaker, but unfortunately no beeping at all. just restarting

Please help

Comment: Section 4 of the manual (first download on https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=1031#download ) has a section 4 on troubleshooting you should work through.  Hopefully your system is producing beeps which can point you in the right ditection.

Comment: As @davidgo says; any beep codes?

Comment: As I said in the question I don’t have the motherboard speaker at the moment I try to find one. I will keep you updated, Thanks

Comment: I just tried to connect the motherboard speaker, but unfortunately no beeping at all. just restarting. I'm so confused now.

Comment: a broken CPU is an extremely rare phenomenon (it's unlikely to be the CPU), but do you have a 2nd cpu you can try?

Comment: @hanshenrik I don't have 2nd CPU but I try to turn on the PC without a CPU fan to check if the CPU gets warm and see if it works well and CPU temp increased. the temp is increased which means the CPU is working. I also tried another PSU with no luck. I'm so confused now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I changed the motherboard, and the problem was fixed. So most probably the problem was caused by the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Like it's power cycling every few seconds?

This sounds like a hardware issue.  Have you checked all your connectors and switches?  Try a new power supply? Just noticed the AliExpress power supply... start there...

Most cases I have seen like this a problem with power to the MoBo or a switch problem with a cheap case/power button.

Keep us updated on what you have checked.

Comment: I tried to remove the ram and insert the speaker, but now the motherboard is beeping without reset after inserting the ram motherboard restarted continuously with no beep sound.

Answer (score 1):

If your PC case is fully metal body then check it is not touching the ground directly. Place some wooden or plastic thing under the PC case and then restart your PC and check if it is working or not.

If not, then follow this full proof method because I have also fixed this issue with this hack.

1. Remove all the peripherals like keyboard, speaker, mouse connected to your Motherboard or the PC Case.
2. Now remove your PC from the main power. ( No electricity should flow  )
3. Now Open your PC Case and then remove all devices like hard drive, CD ROM from the PSU Power Supply Unit.

Once the Power Supply is disconnected from all the devices, now we have to check if Power Supply is working properly or not. ( May be it is not providing the supply fully )

And to check it or jump start, see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea1dcJ0QyAE

Once the Power Supply or fan starts working, I would suggest you keep running it 5-6 minutes like this only. After that, cut off the main power to stop this power Supply.

Now connect all your computer devices again, start your PC and it will start working.

Note:- While connecting all the devices, please make sure no power should be supplied to any device or peripherals.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to remove the ram and insert the speaker, but now the motherboard is beeping without reset after inserting the ram motherboard restarted continuously with no beep sound

Comment: This beep sound only comes when some peripheral are not connected to PC. Please follow the exact mentioned steps, it will work. Because I have also fixed this issue and this is only happening because of the Power Supply problem or some electrostatic issue.

Comment: I did all these steps already and I will check with one new power supply to make sure that does not make a problem.

Comment: Okay, In my opinion this issue is occurring because of the electrostatic charge present in the PC Case or motherboard and once it is removed it will work. Also, is your Power Supply working with Jump Start or not. Please let me know if it works with the new Power Supply.

Comment: Tried with another Power supply but the same story happen.

Comment: One last thing you can try, if you have newly changed the motherboard or PC Case then take out all the part and then run them without the case. Because I have faced this issue for very long time because of small PC case and motherboard was big as compared to old one. Please always use a big PC case so that all the parts can fit easily.

Comment: I don’t use the PC case, it’s a mining rig. But thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I could find in the manual that was relevant was this:

[image]

- Make sure the fan is connected and spinning.
- Make sure your CPU cooler is properly installed.
- Make sure if you are only using one power supply, that it is connected to the first ATX socket.

If none of those help, return your RAM and try new sticks.

If that doesn't help, RMA the mobo.